# does "revolving the disc" caused by "attachments" or "sliding the table"? what is the meaning of "follow" here?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity, reference

does "revolving the disc" caused by "attachments" or "sliding the table"? what is the meaning of "follow" here?

> Mr. S. B. Brittan, editor of The Spiritual Telegraph, gives the
>   following condensed account of some of Hare's experiments:
>   *First, to satisfy himself that the movements were not the works of mortals, he took brass billiard balls, placed them on zinc plates and
>   placed the hands of the mediums on the balls and, to his very great
>   astonishment the tables moved. He next arranged a table to slide
>   backward and forward, to which **attachments** were made, **causing a disc
>   to revolve** containing the alphabet, hidden from the view of the
>   mediums. The letters were variously arranged, out of their regular
>   consecutive order, and the spirit was required to place them
>   consecutively or in their regular places. And behold, it was done!
>   Then **followed** intelligent sentences which the medium could not see or
>   know the import of till they were told him. Again he tried another
>   capital test. The long end of a lever was placed on spiral scales with
>   an index attached and the weight marked; the medium's hand rested on
>   the short end of the beam, where it was impossible to give pressure
>   downward, but if pressed it would have a contrary effect and raise the
>   long end; and yet, most astounding, the weight was increased several
>   pounds on the scale.*

source:http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html _ hos by acd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language is not at all clear, but I read it that the attachments caused the disc to revolve when the table slid.

*Then followed* could be paraphrased as *What came next was*; or simply *Next*, but it would need a verb adding in that case.

Comment: I think "Then followed intelligent sentences" is just an unusual word order for "Intelligent sentences then followed...". It could have been put "Then there followed intelligent sentences..."